# Enable trace/debug for JVM events

Tags: java, jvm

I have some problems with a java process on a heavy loaded machine, where the java processes is stuck for about 40-45 minutes. After those 40-45 minutes everything resumes without any issue.

From what I saw the box is heavy loaded during that time, so my assumption the java process is not scheduled for execution during that time...

Is there any flags I can add to the JVM so I can see what events occurs during that time-frame?

Regards,

Cristi

Comment: Is cpu of jvm nearly 100% during that 40-45 minutes.? if so, you can do thread dump (by using command jstack or tools jconsole / jvisulavm, etc ) analyse the stack traces

Comment: Good point. I've forgot to mention that I am not able to do any jcmd Thread.print, jstack, etc. I receive the following error: AttachNotSupportedException:Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded

Comment: Also, the CPU is not at 100%, but for free memory on that box I saw that only 5 mb were available.

Comment: if you get AttachNotSupportedException, enable jmx by using -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<<port_no>> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false. Then Using jconsole / jvisulavm you can connect

Comment: Thanks. For now I've enabled the VM / GC logs and see what I see there when the process is hung. Afterwards I will try what you said and come back with feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=/var/application/log/`date +%F_%H-%M-%S`_jvm.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/var/application/log/`date +%F_%H-%M-%S`_gc.log
```